# Custom Route/Redirect inside Switch not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

#### Working code example

```js
const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Redirect from="/:url*(/+)" to={window.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, window.location.search)}/>
        {/* Some routes */}
    </Switch>
)
```

#### Extracting the Redirect into a custom component (Not working)

**Note:** The same behaviour occurs with a `Route` component as you can see in the accepted answer.

```js
const Routes: React.FC = () => (
    <Switch>
        <RemoveTrailingSlash />
        {/* Some routes */}
    </Switch>
    )
}

const RemoveTrailingSlash = () => (
    <Redirect from="/:url*(/+)" 
    to={window.location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, window.location.search)} />
)
```

Why isn't it possible to use a custom `Redirect` or `Route` component inside a `Switch` Component?

See an example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-tree-t38tm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do inside `RemoveTrailingSlash` component? What route are you trying to redirect from and what route are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: Routes below the `RemoveTrailingSlash` component don't get rendered because of `Switch`. Try moving `<RemoveTrailingSlash />` above the `Switch` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` component renders the *first* route matching child component. Keeping this in mind, let's look at the difference between the two examples included in your question.

#### First Code Example (working)

```
const Routes: React.FC = () => {
   const location = useLocation()
   
   return (
     <Switch>
       <Redirect 
          from="/:url*(/+)" 
          to={location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, location.search)}
        />
        {/* Some routes */}
     </Switch>
   )
}
```

This code example works because `Redirect` component is rendered conditionally; it is rendered when the url matches the regex of the `from` prop.

So for a path like: `/testing/`, `Redirect` component will be rendered, trailing `/` will be removed and will be redirected to `/testing`.

After the redirect, `Redirect` component will not be rendered because the url doesn't match the regex specified by the `from` prop on the `Redirect` component. So, `Switch` component will skip the `Redirect` component and keep looking for a component that matches the route.

**Breaking the First Code Example**

You can break this example by removing the `from` prop from the `Redirect` component.

```
<Redirect 
  to={location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, location.search)}
/>
```

Doing this will give you the same result as the second non-working code example because now the `Redirect` component will always be the first matching component that will be rendered by the `Switch` component.

#### Second Code Example (not working)

```
const Routes: React.FC = () => {
   const location = useLocation();
    
   return (
     <Switch>
       <RemoveTrailingSlash />
       {/* Some routes */}
     </Switch>
   )
}
    
export const RemoveTrailingSlash = () => { ... }
```

This code example doesn't works as you expect because when you move the `Redirect` component inside a custom component, i.e. `RemoveTrailingSlash`, `Switch` component *always* renders the `RemoveTrailingSlash` component because it is rendered unconditionally.

As soon as the `RemoveTrailingSlash` component is rendered, `Switch` component stops looking for the matching route component. As a result, any component after `RemoveTrailingSlash` is not rendered.

**Fixing the Second Code Example**

You can make the second code example work by moving the `RemoveTrailingSlash` component above the `Switch` component.

```
return (
  <>
    <RemoveTrailingSlash />
    <Switch>
      {/* Some routes */}
    </Switch>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Because of `Switch` component, only `First` component is rendered, `Switch` component stops looking for a matching component after `First` component. See this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/misty-sun-cu3mq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. Really clear, maybe include it also in the answer. So this is the expected behaviour of the `Switch` component and the `from` keyword is just a conditionally render. Thanks.